# Error retrying database insert on SQLException

Tags: java, oracle, error-handling, sqlexception

I have a Java class which loops through a JSON array, parses the data and does inserts to an Oracle database table.

Within each loop iteration I have:

```
try {
    stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL); 
    }
```

DBConnection is a java.sql.Connection object defined in a class I created.  stmt is a java.sql.Statement object.  insertTableSQL is a String having an Oracle insert statement.

When an error occurs, I want to retry the insert, skipping certain columns that can cause an error.  The statement is failing.

```
  catch (SQLException e) {
      stmt.close();
      stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
      insertTableSQL =  "...";
      stmt.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
 }
```

These are the errors:

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:999)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1822)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1787)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:280)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Post complete stack trace. You missed some lines it seems. Post value of `insertTableSQL` too

Comment: Given what you've posted it's impossible to know what went wrong. You haven't shown us your data, your SQL, or the Oracle error message (usually contains "ORA-"). Please edit your question and include more information. Thanks.

Comment: It turns out the query was badly formed.  The issue is resolved.  Thanks!